# Durandal router not activated

Tags: javascript, messagebox, durandal

I have a messageBox in my Durandal app and whether you click no or yes you are sent throw to an other page. I want to do this with the router, but the pages aren't switched.

I can see the code is executing the line but nothing happens!

```
define(function(require) {
var app = require('durandal/app'),
    system = require('durandal/system'),
    router = require('durandal/plugins/router');

return {
    router: router,
    displayName: 'SometingApp Startpage',
    activate: function() {
        system.log("Application started!");
    },
    createEstimate: function() {
        app.showMessage('Do you want to create a new something?', 'New something', ['Yes', 'No']).then(function(result) {
            if (result == "Yes") {
                return router.activate('otherpage');
            }
        });
    }
};
```

});

THe user click a button that is bind to createEstimate!

Hope someone can help!

Comment: where are you activating the router? and how are you mapping the routes to modules? Can you show your compose binding on your view also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you need to do is call router.navigateTo('#/yourUrl').

If i understand right the documentation, router.activate must be call only one time, usually at the shell activation.

The route functions available for your viewModel navigation is listed in the documentation

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Router/ under the section "Other APIs"

Comment: That didn't do the trick, sorry. I have the routers configured correctly in main.js, this accordingly to the Durandal documentary

Comment: Are there any error messages on console when calling router.navigateTo?

Comment: None ;(, there is nothing in my console or what so ever!

Comment: I don't know if that can make any difference, but your are not closing the modal. Try to close it before navigating to the new view.

Comment: It already does close my modal http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Showing-Message-Boxes-And-Modals/ 

See Messagebox.JS when a button is clicked it executes: this.modal.close(dialogResult);

Comment: Leroy - I tested this with router.navigateTo('#/otherpage') and router.replaceLocation('#/otherpage'). Seems to be working fine.  What version of Durandal and browser?

Comment: Damn, long live a good night of sleep. I was dead starring an router.activate :S should have been router.navigateTo.

So credits in first place to @JUlian ;) Thanks

I'm using Durandal the starterskit and customizing this to my own comforts. Writing my own Shell etc..